# array('category') : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

```
public function get($id = null)
{
    $terms                  = array('id' => $id);
    $blog                   = $this->model->getBy($terms); 

    // $blog => (object) [id => 1, category_id => 3]

    $fix->id                = $blog->id;
    // $fix->category       = $this->getCategory($blog->category_id); // Not work
    $fix->cat_or_something = $this->getCategory($blog->category_id); // Work

    return $fix;

    // $fix => (object) [id => 1, cat_or_something => [name => Some Category]]
}
```

If I change `$fix->category` with `$fix->cat_or_something`, it will work. There's something strange about the `$fix->category`.

Comment: the code posted may not be the problem... Are you echoing `$fix` anywhere? you may need to write a `__toString()` function for the object to be successfully converted to a String

Comment: Can you post the full definition of the class `$fix` and a `var_dump($this->get_category($blog->category_id));` please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not providing a solution earlier to solve the challenges that caused my problem.

The problem was caused by two interconnected issues:

- A caching problem
- Library incompatibility with the current PHP version. This led to conflicts between the PHP version being used and the libraries used in the code.

Fortunately, the issue was resolved by reinstalling PHP, which involved installing and integrating a newer and compatible version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere else in your code.
You most probably are trying to echo $fix->category somewhere, and since it contains an object you get an error.

**Edit 2:**

After looking at it some more, I'm still going with my initial answer. If you look at the 3rd version of your code in your  screenshot ( http://d.pr/i/4Hn7 ) you'll see that the error occurs after the print_r, so also after assigning it to $fix->category - so that's not the problem

The error occurs in the **DB_active_rec.php**. That's the _where() method in my version (2.0).
So that would mean that you're trying to use $fix->category in a where clausule somewhere... Try looking into that.

Comment: So if you were to echo $blog->category_id you'll get a string (or integer)? If yes, then could you post the get_category method as well?