# Undefined property: stdClass codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

`Undefined property: stdClass alamat`

in my view where I take ,

> $this->data['prodi']  = $this->mprodi->get_all_prodi();

In my controller view I am getting this error. But when I am not take my select `prodi` is not shown.

This is my view :

```
<div class="field">
     <label>Piih Prodi</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="nama_prodi" value="<?php echo $data->nama_prodi;?>"><?php echo form_error('nama_prodi', '<div class="ui red pointing label">', '</div>'); ?>
     <select name="prodi" id="select_prodi">
       <?php foreach ($prodi as $prodi_data) :?>
       <?php echo '<option value="'.$prodi_data->id_prodi.'">'.$prodi_data->nama_prodi.'</option>'; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

      </select>
   </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Fakultas</label>
    <div class="ui small left icon input">
      <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="fakultas" class="fakultas" placeholder="fakultas" name="nama_fakultas"> 
      <i class="text file outline icon"></i>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
    <label>Alamat</label>
    <textarea placeholder="text" name="alamat">
    <?php echo $data->alamat;?>
    </textarea><?php echo form_error('alamat', '<div class="ui red pointing label">', '</div>'); ?>
    </div>
```

*Controller :*

```
function edit_anggota($nim='')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nim', 'nim', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required'););
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('geup', 'Geup', 'required');


        //$nim = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $nim = $this->input->post('old_nim');
        $this->data['prodi']    = $this->mprodi->get_all_prodi();

        if (!empty($_POST)) 
        {
            $data['nim']            = $this->input->post('nim');
            $data['email']          = $this->input->post('email');
            $data['no_telp']        = $this->input->post('no_telp');
            $data['tempat_lahir']   = $this->input->post('tempat_lahir');
            $data['tanggal_lahir']  = $this->input->post('tanggal_lahir');
            $data['tanggal_lahir']  = $this->input->post('tanggal_lahir');
            $data['jenis_kelamin']  = $this->input->post('jenis_kelamin');
            $data['angkatan']       = $this->input->post('angkatan');
            $data['agama']          = $this->input->post('agama');
            $data['id_prodi']       = $this->input->post('id_prodi');
            $data['alamat']         = $this->input->post('alamat');
            $data['sabuk']          = $this->input->post('sabuk');
            $data['geup']           = $this->input->post('geup');


            if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) 
            {
                $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '5000';
                $config['max_width']  = '10240';
                $config['max_height']  = '7680';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))     
                {
                    if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']==0) 
                    {
                        // echo "<pre>";
                        // print_r($_POST);
                        // print_r($_FILES);
                        // print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
                        // exit;
                        $this->mdaftar->update_daftar($nim,$data);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', generateSuccessMessage('Data berhasil diupdate'));
                        redirect(site_url('anggota/profil/edit_anggota'));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->data['error']= $this->upload->display_errors();

                        $this->data['id_user']  = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
                        $this->data['orang']    = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
                        $this->data['data']     = $this->mdaftar->get_daftar_detail($this->data['id_user']);

                        $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('anggota/edit_profil', $this->data, true);
                        $this->load->view('template/wrapper/mahasiswa/wrapper_sign',$this->data);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $datafoto=$this->upload->data();
                    $nm_file =$datafoto['file_name'];
                    $data['image']= $nm_file;

                    $this->mdaftar->update_daftar($nim,$data);
                    // print_r($this->mdaftar->update_daftar($nim,$data));
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', generateSuccessMessage('Data berhasil diupdate'));
                    redirect(site_url('anggota/profil/edit_anggota'));
                }


            }
            else
            {

                $this->data['id_user']  = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
                $this->data['detail']   = $this->mdaftar->get_daftar_detail($this->data['id_user']);
                $this->data['orang']    = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
                $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('anggota/edit_profil', $this->data, true);
                $this->load->view('template/wrapper/mahasiswa/wrapper_sign',$this->data);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data['id_user']  = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            $this->data['data']     = $this->mdaftar->get_daftar_detail($this->data['id_user']);
            $this->data['orang']    = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
            $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('anggota/edit_profil', $this->data, true);
            $this->load->view('template/wrapper/mahasiswa/wrapper_sign',$this->data);
        }
    }
```

modal

```
    function get_daftar_detail($id_user)//$limit = 10, $offset = 0)
    {
        //$this->db->order_by('id','asc');
        //$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->join('prodi','prodi.id_prodi = mahasiswa.id_prodi','left');
        $this->db->join('pendaftaran_anggota','pendaftaran_anggota.nim = mahasiswa.nim','left');
        $this->db->join('anggota','anggota.id_anggota = pendaftaran_anggota.id_anggota','left');
        $this->db->join('user','user.id_user = anggota.id_user','left');
        $this->db->where('user.id_user',$id_user);
        //$this->db->join('prodi','prodi.id_prodi = mahasiswa.id_prodi','join');
        $data = $this->db->get('mahasiswa'); 
        return $data->row();

    }

function get_all_prodi()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('id_prodi','desc');
        $data = $this->db->get($this->tbl_prodi);
        return $data->result();
    }
```

Please tell me what to do.

Thank you

Comment: Kok ga ada `get_all_prodi()` method di model?

Comment: get_all_prodi dibuat method sendiri mas.

Comment: Try `var_dump($prodi)` in view and what the result?

Comment: i try <?php var_dump($prodi); ?> but no result.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have end your foreach loop before print that variable 
try this one

```
<label>Piih Prodi</label>
       <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="nama_prodi" value="<?php echo $data->nama_prodi;?>"><?php echo form_error('nama_prodi', '<div class="ui red pointing label">', '</div>'); ?>
        <select name="prodi" id="select_prodi">
         <?php foreach ($prodi as $data) :?>
         <?php echo '<option value="'.$data->id_prodi.'">'.$data->nama_prodi.'</option>'; ?>

  // Other code ..

           <div class="field">
            <label>Alamat</label>
             <textarea placeholder="text" name="alamat">
              <?php echo $data->alamat;?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
              </textarea><?php echo form_error('alamat', '<div class="ui red pointing label">', '</div>'); ?>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It just because you have `$data` variable.

```
$this->data['data'] = $this->mdaftar->get_daftar_detail($this->data['id_user']);
```

And you use `$data` - `foreach`.

```
<?php foreach ($prodi as $data) :?>
```

You need change it.

```
<?php foreach ($prodi as $prodi_data) :?>
```

---

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Piih Prodi</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="nama_prodi" value="
    <?php echo $data->nama_prodi;?>">
    <?php echo form_error('nama_prodi', '
    <div class="ui red pointing label">', '</div>'); ?>
    <select name="prodi" id="select_prodi">
        <?php 
        foreach ($prodi as $prodi_data)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$prodi_data->id_prodi.'">'.$prodi_data->nama_prodi.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label>Fakultas</label>
    <div class="ui small left icon input">
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="fakultas" class="fakultas" placeholder="fakultas" name="nama_fakultas">
        <i class="text file outline icon"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label>Alamat</label>

        <?php
        // We need to check $data.
        // Please comment what the result. Paste in comment.
        var_dump($data);
        ?>

    <textarea placeholder="text" name="alamat">
        <?php echo $data->alamat;?>
    </textarea>
    <?php echo form_error('alamat', '<div class="ui red pointing label">', '</div>'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: i already change like that but still error. you can see view i always edit. may be any something wrong.

Comment: What error you get? And what you get with `<?php foreach ($prodi as $prodi_data) : var_dump($prodi_data); ?>`?

Comment: its same Undefined property: stdClass::$alamat

Comment: i try var_dump like that ini view is no result but i try var_dump in controller prodi get all name of prodi in university.

Comment: @user3622745 please comment the result. Updating my answer.

Comment: Untuk akses `$data->nim` bisa? Apa error juga? Loh kok beda lagi resultnya seperti yang diedit sebelumnya..

Comment: untuk akses $data->nim bisa. hanya alamat yang tidak bisa. tapi jika $this->data['prodi'] = $this->mprodi->get_all_prodi(); dihilangkan dari controller alamat dapat akses namun nama prodi tidak tampil. sama mas isinya cuma saya ambil beberapa aja soalnya isinya terlalu banyak.

Comment: Bisa kasih saya full view-nya? Mungkin di pastebin. Sepertinya ada yang di bypass

Comment: Kalau pakai yang ini gimana? http://pastebin.com/uctXsZZd. Ini kasusnya unik. Gw pernah alamin juga..

Comment: itu yang dipastebin yang dirubah cuma $data-alamat jadi $alamat kan? kalo cuma pake $alamat aja tetep error Undefined variable: alamat.

Comment: Iya. Tapi harusnya ga akan Undefined variable: alamat. Aku analisa lagi deh.. Kasusnya kayanya hampir sama kaya pertanyaanku http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102554/arraycategory-object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-string

Comment: oke mas aku udah bingung tinggal satu error ini selesai tapi gak nemu-nemu :D

Comment: Tapi anehnya kenapa `$alamat` ga bisa diakses? Kan udah jelas itu ada.. Kamu yakin udah set var `$alamat = $data->alamat` kan?

Comment: ngeset var $alamat = $data->alamat dimna?

Comment: Di view.. Yang tadi di pastebin saya kasih.. Itu ada dibagian paling atas. Nah nanti yang `$data->alamat` ganti dengan dengan `$alamat`.

Comment: ttp sama mas errornya jadi <p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: stdCla

Comment: Im on chat ya.. Biar gampang.